# unable to add elements to array in bash after looping on elements in var

Tags: bash

Team: probably this is asked many times but am unable to resolve my situatuion.
unable to add all looped matched elements to array `bazel_cov_req` and just outputs first element that was inserted.

I am adding git changed dir paths to variable and then am looping on all of them and then adding them to an array for later use. but my array is not getting populated with all and it is just showing me one entry.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -v -e -o pipefail
bazel_cov_req=() #declared it here for global access.

bazel_coverage_pba() {
#    bazel_cov_req=()
    bbf="BUILD.bazel"
    mr_changed_paths=$(git diff HEAD~1 --name-only | grep -e "src/" | xargs dirname | sort | uniq)
    # echo $mr_changed_paths
    for apath in ${mr_changed_paths[@]}; do
        echo "checking for $apath\n"
        if [ -f "$apath/$bbf" ]; then
            echo "$apath is a bazel path"
            echo "add this path to bazel_coverage_required array"
            bazel_cov_req+=($apath)
            echo "array of paths to be bazel covered\n"
            echo {$bazel_cov_req[@]}
        else
            echo -e "\tbazel build not found under $apath so skip in coverage"
            echo "search a --dir in same path $apath"
            #code here to find file in pre path.
        fi  
    done
   
}

bazel_coverage_pba
```

output

```
checking for src/test/secrets\n
    src/test/secrets is a bazel path
add this path to bazel_coverage_required array
array of paths to be bazel covered\n
{src/test/secrets[@]}
checking for src/test/team\n
    src/test/team is a bazel path
add this path to bazel_coverage_required array
array of paths to be bazel covered\n
{src/test/secrets[@]}
checking for src/ui/automation\n
    bazel build not found under src/ui/automation so skip in coverage
search a --dir in same path src/ui/automation
```

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Paste the contents of your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and implement the suggested changes.

Comment: please update the question to show the (correct) expected output

Comment: below answer helped. i chose it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue:

```
echo {$bazel_cov_req[@]}
```

To `bash` this looks like:

```
echo "{" $bazel_cov_req "[@]}"
```

Which is expanded to:

```
echo "{" ${bazel_cov_req[0]} "[@]}"

#     {  src/test/secrets     [@]}
```

Net result is that on each pass through the loop you're only displaying the first item in the array (`$bazel_cov_req` == `${bazel_cov_req[0]`).

Assuming you want to display the entire contents of the array then try:

```
echo "${bazel_cov_req[@]}"
```

Alternatively:

```
typeset -p bazel_cov_req
```